# japanize-matplotlibのインストールエラーについて

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda3, conda

https://github.com/uehara1414/japanize-matplotlib
に従って、Anaconda Promptで
`conda install -c uehara1414 japanize-matplotlib`
を実行した所で下記のように青枠のエラーが発生しました。

エラー原因と改善方法を教えていただきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: エラーメッセージは画像ではなく文字のまま質問に貼り付けてください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
以後、気を付けていきたいと思います。


＜エラーメッセージ＞
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Comment: 一応これらのIssue [conda 経由でインストールできるようにする #18](https://github.com/uehara1414/japanize-matplotlib/issues/18), [condaでのインストール方法についての記述を追加 #22](https://github.com/uehara1414/japanize-matplotlib/pull/22) で出来るようになったようなので、出来ないのであれば何かAnacondaやcondaの版数とか他を含めた環境が影響しているのかもしれません。そうした場合はこちらの記事 [Python/matplotlibで日本語文字列を使う](https://azusa.shinshu-u.ac.jp/~hasegawa/class/programming/index.php?Python/matplotlib%E3%81%A7%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86), [1分で簡単！Matplotlibの日本語対応を徹底解説！](https://ai-inter1.com/matplotlib-japanize/) の方法で試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: ありがとうございます！問題が解決しました。
「condaの版数」という言葉が気になり、 https://github.com/uehara1414/japanize-matplotlib をよく見たところ、installerがWin_64に対応していないことが分かりました。なので、pipでインストールを行うことにしました。使用環境がWindows 11であることを記述しておらず申し訳ありません。
しかし、おかげさまで問題が解決しましたので、もしよろしければ回答をするでお返事をいただけたら幸いです。